# Error The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: c#, wcf

I read the questions:

But those don't solve my issue, yet.

I have a web service: `Service1` and application `App1` which connects to `Service1` through port 8089.

The config of `App1`

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferPoolSize="327680" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" sendTimeout="00:01:30">
              <security mode="Transport" />
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="327680" maxBytesPerRead="327680" maxDepth="327680" maxNameTableCharCount="327680" maxStringContentLength="104857600" />
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>

          <endpoint address="http://localhost:8089/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="Service1Client.IService1"
                    name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

and config of `Service1`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="327680" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="327680" maxBytesPerRead="327680" maxDepth="327680" maxNameTableCharCount="327680" maxStringContentLength="104857600"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Service1.Contract.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8089/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I got error:

> The message with To 'http://localhost:8089/' cannot be processed at
>   the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Contract Reference is the same version as the Server.